# Unable to see the import webdriver option after adding the selenium 4.10 jars into Project folder buildpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I never faced this issue before . After 4 years I tried to begin the selenium with latest java version, Eclispe and Selenium webdriver but now I am facing very cheap issue to start the webdriver import. I tried properly by watching the youtube tutorial but I couldn't resolve this and It sucks my entire day to resolve this. Please someone help me. [image]

Tried to import webdriver to launch the browser but I couldn't see the import webdriver.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.